Como puedo detectar el "Enter" en Javascript?
estoy con un inconveniente que  no encuentro la manera de hacerlo; estoy necesitando detectar la pulsación del botón "enter" del teclado una vez que el usuario haya terminado de ingresar datos, pero lo que detecta es: cada vez que el usuario ingresa cualquier dato ya ejecuta la función intentar() que hace la validación de los datos.
HTML:
<input type="text" id="guess-input" maxlength="5" pattern="a-z" required>
JavaScript:
var INPUT = document.getElementById("guess-input");
INPUT.addEventListener('keydown',intentar());

Así se presenta cada vez que se ingrese una letra, es decir ya detectó la letra y ejecutó intentar()


a ver, edita tu pregunta y agrega la función intentar, por que tienes algo que me parece extraño

Hola Willian, bienvenido, puedes probar: document.addEventListener("keydown", (ev) => {
ev.preventDefault();
if(  ev.key === "Enter" ){
alert( "presiono Enter" ); }
}
);.

si alguna de las respuesta te ha servido podes marcarla como resuelta, eso te dara al menos 2 puntos de reputacion que te seran utiles en un futuro. saludos.

Para una buena comprensión, el segundo argumento de addEventListener es una función callback que siempre se ejecutará cuando ocurra el evento


const INPUT = document.getElementById("guess-input");

function intentar(event){
  if (event.key === "Enter") {
    alert("Presionó la tecla enter")
    event.preventDefault();      
         }
}


INPUT.addEventListener("keypress", intentar)
<input type="text" id="guess-input" maxlength="5" pattern="a-z" required>



Para más referencias, consulta developer.mozilla.

JavaScript:

Primero, nos aseguramos de que el DOM esté completamente cargado utilizando DOMContentLoaded.

Luego, cargamos un eventListener al campo de entrada para escuchar el evento keydown.

Dentro del eventListener, debemos verificar si la tecla presionada es la tecla "Enter" con (event.key === 'Enter').


Si es así, entonces debemos hacer la llamada a la función intentar(), donde puedes poner tu lógica de validación de datos.
Este seria el codigo de ejemplo que yo implementaria:


document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
    var input = document.getElementById("guess-input");
    input.addEventListener('keydown', function(event) {
        if (event.key === 'Enter') {
            intentar();
        }
    });
});

function intentar() {
    // Aquí va tu lógica de validación de datos
    alert('Se ha pulsado Enter y se ejecuta la función intentar.');
}
<input type="text" id="guess-input" maxlength="5" pattern="[a-zA-Z]" required>



